# Ionic ios-sim throws error

Tags: ios-simulator, ionic-framework

I have the following error when running `ionic emulate ios`

```
2014-10-29 10:21:52.540 ios-sim[1992:507] stderrPath:     /Users/***/Desktop/apps/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2014-10-29 10:21:52.541 ios-sim[1992:507] stdoutPath: /Users/***/Desktop/apps/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
Usage of '--family' is deprecated in 3.x. Use --devicetypeid instead.
Usage of '--retina' is deprecated in 3.x. Use --devicetypeid instead.
Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Simulator    session timed out." UserInfo=0x7f9b09709470 {NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator session timed out.}
Error: /Users/***/Desktop/apps/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process
.js:756:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

This started happening when i upgrades to xcode 6

Comment: Have you updated Cordova recently? `sudo npm update cordova` and `sudo npm update ios-sim` should make sure they are up to date.

Comment: thats has not solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

> Session could not be started: Error
>   Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Simulator    session timed
>   out." UserInfo=0x7f9b09709470 {NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator
>   session timed out.}

This error indicates that Xcode (or whatever is printing the error) was waiting for the iOS Simulator.app to launch and boot a specific simulator device, but it never got a notification that the simulated device finished booting.

Similar issues have been reported when trying to run within an ssh session or from a LaunchDaemon (but you should be able to do it just fine from a LaunchAgent).